# Trying to deploy static, custom map with clickable markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have static images of map areas and I need to display them with a clickable marker overlay with multiple dynamic markers on it. The markers have to correspond to specific geo locations. I will know the geo coordinates of the markers, but they will change frequently.

The static images HAVE to be displayed without any of the surrounding areas visible (and- NO zoom, no drag, no pan etc). For example, a map of a state in the USA with NO bordering states and multiple, specifically placed, clickable markers. This makes it impossible to use google maps api as is even with map style customization (at least for the actual map display).

So my question(s) is/are:

1. Is there a way to do this while still leveraging the google map api marker functionality? Or will I have to rewrite my own version of the marker functionality (click, info box etc)?
2. Is there a way to load the google map with the markers and then dynamically "swap" the google map with my static one?

Picture this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [nebdev.net](http://web2.nebdev.net/tasks/sandbox/untitled3.png))</sub>

Where the markers are clickable and positioned based on specific geo codes.

Comment: To add to the below answers, you can also check how to [style a map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling). This would allow you to hide everything so that only your overlay would be displayed. Also check the [Styled Map Wizard](http://www.dwzone-it.com/StyledMapWizard/StyledMapWizard.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it to work. The concept is pretty simple:

1. Create a non-Google Map overlay OVER the map area to hide the gmap as it's loading. I had to do this because otherwise, the marker wouldn't load correctly.
2. Once the map and marker(s) are loaded, remove all images from inside the map element.
3. Set the background image of the map element to our custom map
4. Remove the overlay that was obscuring the map area.

Demo: http://web2.nebdev.net/tasks/sandbox/t1234.html

Here is the code (it may explain things better than I am):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple markers</title>
        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
        function initialize() {
            //$('#map-canvas').hide();
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: myLatlng,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                draggable: false,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                keyboardShortcuts: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                noClear: true,
                overviewMapControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                rotateControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                scrollwheel: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                zoomControl: false
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            });
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker,'click',function() {alert('Click')});
            //google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker,'mouseover',function() {alert('Mouseover')});
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(map,'idle',removeMaps);
        }

        function removeMaps() {
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('img','#map-canvas').remove();
                $('.gm-style-cc,.gmnoprint .gm-style-cc,.gmnoprint').remove()
                $('#map-canvas').show();
                $('#map-canvas').attr('style','background:url(http://web2.nebdev.net/tasks/sandbox/untitled4.png) no-repeat top left transparent');
                $('#map-canvas-overlay').hide();
                console.log(marker.getVisible());
            },1000);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
        <div id="map-canvas-overlay" style="width:400px;height:400px;background:url() #CCC;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:10000">Loading...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your answers are:

1. Yes.
2. Yes.

Disable controls: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI

Stylized map markers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

Listening to click/DOM events: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of map options, stylized markers and dom listeners. It's the CUSTOM map part that is giving me problems.

Comment: you are probably thinking of map overlays: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this quesiton. But I'm afraid you cannot make what you want.

At lease, you can try these things with Google Maps:
1. Specify the bounds you need (to match your static image) -- Google API
2. Add markers  -- Google API
3. Disable draggable and ScrollWheelZoom  -- Google API
4. Add click event on markers  -- Google API
5. Replace the map with your static image  -- Google API

The problem will be the 1st step, which you can hardly specify the bounds of Google Map as exactly to the area of your static image.

You can specify an area on Google Map though, like [area layer](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/layers/layers.html) , but basically the outer space will still be a rectange(Google Map itself and LatLngBounds)